# A Chinese remainder theorem problem from 1997 slovak math olympiad

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

[image]

**Doubt**

I try to understand this question and solution . But i can not understand the red underlined section. Please can someone explain this solution .And what does it mean finately many prime . I know the chinese remainder theorem .

Comment: Nearly everything is underlined in red. Look at it from the point of view of the $k$'s. If you fix a non-negative $k$, then on all elements $a_n$ of the sequence, for $n\geq k$ we will impose the condition that $p_{k+1}|a_n+k$. Note that for a fixed $n$ only finitely many of these conditions are imposed. Note also how these divisibility conditions are the same as the condition of $a_n$ having remainder $-k$ after division by $p_{k+1}$. So, the CRT can come and select a value for $a_n$ that works.

Comment: e.g. table below shows there are finitely many CRT conditions on $\color{#c00}{a_4}$ since $\rm\color{#c00}{3rd\ column}$ is eventually blank, and $\rm\color{#c00}{3rd\ row}$ shows $\color{#c00}{p_4}$ eventually divides all $\,\color{#c00}{3+a_n}\,$ (i.e. for all $\,n > \color{#c00}3)\ \ $

Comment: $$\begin{align}
&p_2\mid 1\!+\!a_2,\, 1\!+\!a_3,\, \color{#c00}{1\!+\!a_4},\, 1\!+\!a_5,\ 1\!+\!a_6,\, 1\!+\!a_7,\ \ldots\\  
&p_3\mid \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2\!+\!a_3,\, \color{#c00}{2\!+\!a_4},\, 2\!+\!a_5,\ 2\!+\!a_6,\, 2\!+\!a_7,\ \ldots\\
&\color{#c00}{p_4\ \mid}\:\!\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \color{#c00}{3\!+\!a_4,\, 3\!+\!a_5,\ 3\!+\!a_6,\, 3\!+\!a_7,\ \ldots}\\  
&p_5\mid \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 4\!+\!a_5,\ 4\!+\!a_6,\, 4\!+\!a_7,\ \ldots\end{align}\qquad$$

Comment: @BillDubuque Sir how 3+ an divide by p4 and what is the value of an for which 3+an divide by p4?Sir why you remove a1 , a2 , a3 in every column respectively?

Comment: The table displays all imposed divisibilities. In our example, $\rm\color{#c00}{row\ 3}$ shows that eventually (i.e. for $n > \color{#c00}3)$ all elements in $\color{#c00}{3+a_n}$ are divisible by $\color{#c00}{p_4}$ so the only prime that may appear in this infinite tail is the prime $p_4$. Further only $\rm\color{#0a0}{finitely}$ many primes occur in the (undisplayed = blank) $\rm\color{#0a0}{finite}$ initial  sequence preceding the displayed tail (i.e. where $n\le 3),\,$ so in total the sequence $\color{#c00}{3+a_n}$ contains only finitely many primes.

Comment: Similarly for the sequence $k+a_n$ via the $k$'th row, which shows $p_{k+1}\mid k+a_n$ for all $n> k.\ \ $

Comment: Note that $\,a\mid b\,$ means $\,a\,$ divides $\,b,\,$ e.g. the $\rm\color{#c00}{3rd\ row}$ means $\,p_4\,$ divides $\,3+a_4\,$ and $\,3+a_5\,$ and $\,\ldots\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque sir  what is the value of an for which 3+an divide by p4? here p4 is 5 ?

Comment: $p_4 = 5$ divides $3+a_n$ for all $n\ge 4\,$ (that's what the 3rd row displays). $\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque what are the values of the elements in this increasing sequence ? And p4 should be 7 ? 4th prime is 7

Comment: what is the value of a nth term

Comment: @BillDubuque sir what is the value of every terms in this sequence